# Is it possible to cache a CGRect in NSCache?

Tags: objective-c, ios

So I have this method:

```
 rect = CGRectFromString([self.indexToRectMap objectForKey:key]);
```

which is repeatedly called over and over again. So I wanted to know if there's a way to cache this or an alternative to calling this?

Comment: You've already got it "cached". Just save `rect` -- turn it into an ivar, maybe.

Comment: Or, um, just keep getting it from the dictionary that you're getting it from. Why do you assume that getting it from an `NSCache` would be faster than getting it from that dictionary? Although JustSid's suggestion below, to use `NSValue` to wrap the rect in an object is almost certainly better than using `NSString` as you're currently doing.

Answer (score 3):

You can save the rect inside a `NSValue` and then put this into the cache. There are already [convenient methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/NSValue_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html) for storing and retrieving `CGRect`s in `NSValue` implemented, so it should be easy to implement.